# Where to store complex configurations for an Azure Functions app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, application-settings, azure-application-settings

I already know about the Azure App Configuration for storing application configurations such as connection strings for my Azure apps. However, I am now working on an Azure Functions app where I have to store a more complex configuration for my application.

The configuration consists of mappings where for each entry I have a key/id and multiple values associated with it. Ideally, I'd like to store this in a database table, but setting up a whole database just to store this configuration seems a bit excessive to me. There will be about 200 entries in this table and I don't expect this number to grow much in the future.
Is there a way to store this in a way how it can easily be edited later using an Azure App Configuration, or do I really need to create a new database just for this purpose? Is there maybe another alternative which I didn't consider so far?

Answer (score 1):

*Following suggestion is under the assumption that you are not going to edit that data frequently*

One way to do is to create a hash table and store in `configuration` section in Function App. During run time, you can access the data. And for editing you just need to copy whole data from config section , edit it (using notepad++) and update it back to config section.

Though this is not an ideal way , it’s far better than having an dedicated DB just for this purpose ( plus the DB cost )

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Do you have an example for this? I am not exactly sure what you mean when saying `hash table`.

Comment: Something like below in a key-pair format.                                               
   @{

“key1” = “value1”

“key2” = “value2”

}